# Android load shortcut icon from web

Tags: android, android-intent

This is how I am getting an icon right now:

```
    Intent shortcutIntent = getShortcutIntent();

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, mAppData.title);

    Intent.ShortcutIconResource shortcutIconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(MainApplication.getAppContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, shortcutIconResource);
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    MainApplication.getAppContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

I would like for the icon to be loaded from the web. is this a possibility?